# How to save same document in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const test_schema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    Name: {
        type: String
    }
});

const chatting = mongoose.model('chat', test_schema);
module.exports = chatting;
```

Getting model of above give the schema

```
const chat = require('./models/chatting.js');
```

Save Variables

```
const one = new chat({
    Name : "John"
})

const two = new chat({
    Name : "John"
})
```

Now Saving

```
 await chat.insertMany([one, two])
```

but i got *duplicate name key error*

Comment: What is `test_schema` and `chatting_schema`?

Answer (score 0):

You provided a wrong schema to us. (test_schema != chatting_schema). check your chatting schema and see if it is structured somewhat like this:

```
const chatting_schema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    Name: {
        type: String
        unique: true
    }
});
```

if so, remove the unique property.

also, when you already created a document you can just use the .save() function like

```
await one.save();
```